# In Django, how do you get a count of the records in the through table that relate back to an object?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

How do you get the count of the records in a table through a through table that relate backwards?

**EDIT: I've simplified the models.**

How do I get the number of times an author quotes other authors? I'd prefer to do this from the `self` object if possible, but if not, I could use `annotate()` or `aggregate()`. But how?

**My models**

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @property
    def times_quoted_by_other_authors(self):
        return self.authors_quoted_books.count()

    @property
    def times_quoted_other_authors(self):
        pass
        # What do I return here

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author_books',
        null=True
    )
    authors_quoted = models.ManyToManyField(
        Author,
        related_name='authors_quoted_books'
    )
```

The SQL query for `times_quoted_other_authors` is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS times_quoted_other_authors
FROM authors_book_authors_quoted
WHERE book_id IN (SELECT id
                  FROM authors_book
                  WHERE author_id = 1);
```

Comment: It seems like my answer was not what you're looking for so I removed it.

Comment: @schillingt, Thanks for trying. I've simplified the models if that helps..

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work using aggregate:

```
@property
def times_quoted_other_authors(self):
    return Book.objects.filter(author=self).aggregate(
        count=Count('authors_quoted')
    )['count']
```

Be sure to import `Count`

```
from django.db.models import Count
```